# Backbone div not being repainted

Tags: backbone.js

I am using a Router for my navigation and layout management (is that right!?) and seem to have a hit a problem:

```
backboneQuote.Routers.ApplicationRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
    "" : "home",
    "edit/:id": "quoteEdit"
},

initialize: function(){
    this.headerView = new backboneQuote.Views.headerView();
    $('.header').html(this.headerView.render().el);

    if(!this.itemsView){
        this.items = new backboneQuote.Collections.ApplicationCollection([
            {id: 1, name: "item 1"},
            {id: 2, name: "item 2"},
            {id: 3, name: "item 3"}
        ]);

        this.itemsView = new backboneQuote.Views.itemsView({collection: this.items});
    }
    this.content = $('.container');
},

home: function(){

    this.content.html(this.itemsView.render());

},

quoteEdit: function(id){
    this.editQuoteView = new backboneQuote.Views.editQuoteView({model: this.items.where({id: parseInt(id, 10)})});
    $('#editQuote').html(this.editQuoteView.render().el);
    this.content.html($('#editQuote').html());
}
```

});

My itemsView render stuff:

```
renderItem: function(model){
    var itemView = new backboneQuote.Views.itemView({model: model});
    itemView.render();
    $(this.el).append(itemView.el);
    return this;
},

render: function(){
    this.collection.each(this.renderItem);
},
```

I click an element which navigates the app back to the "home" function (the click event is firing fine), but the content of "this.itemsView" never seem to get put back into "this.content" div. Can anyone spot anything wrong here?

As another massive help, if anyone could provide any overall BackboneJS wisdom on anything they see here then that would be a *massive* help.

Comment: In the home function, `render` does not return html. You need to call the `.el` property on it, the way you have done in `qouteEdit`. I am assuming this was a typo in the question and not in the code.

Comment: @AmithGeorge You'd think it might be a typo, but no, I'm still learning! I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined" when I add .el on the end...

Comment: You mean `this.itemsView.render()` is returning undefined? Could you verify if the `render` function in itemsView has the `return this;` at the end of it?

Comment: @AmithGeorge Edited my Q. I appreciate your patience!

Comment: Had any luck with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, in Backbone apps, we write the `render` method to set the content of the views `el`. It is the responsibility of the code that calls `render` to ensure that the `el` is shown at the right place.

In the router,

```
home: function(){

    this.content.html(this.itemsView.render());

},
```

you are not accessing the `.el`  property. First fix is to add that there.

```
home: function(){

    this.itemsView.render();
    this.content.html(this.itemsView.el);

},
```

This assumes that your collection view has an `el` property, which Backbone views by default tend to have.

Considering this is such a common task, the convention is to return `this` at the end of each views `render` method.

```
render: function(){
    this.collection.each(this.renderItem);
    return this;
 },

home: function(){
    this.content.html(this.itemsView.render().el);
},
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, thanks for this. This helped a lot, it didn't solve my problem but did help!